# How to prevent jumping xtic labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This will illustrate the meaning. How I get all xlabels on a baseline?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-0.1:0.1,yticklabel style={scaled ticks=false,
                             /pgf/number format/fixed,
                             /pgf/number format/precision=3},
yticklabel={%
\pgfmathprintnumberto[verbatim,fixed,precision=3]{\tick\possiblytrimmedtick%
\pgfmathparse{\possiblytrimmedtick == \tick ? int(1):int(0)}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\relax$\tick$\else\fi%
}
]
\addplot+ { x^3 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks.
JT

Comment: what do you mean by getting all the `xlabels` on a baseline?

Comment: I mean the change between scientific notation 10e2 and 10, which leads to the labels jumping up to the x-axis. I want to have the identifiers on a baseline regardless of the presence of exponents.

Comment: could you update that in your question as well? Because, as it is now, it is unclear what you want :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set option `typeset ticklabels with strut` for the `axis` environment:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% <- missing package added
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=-0.1:0.1,
  yticklabel style={
    scaled ticks=false,
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/precision=3
  },
  yticklabel={%
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[verbatim,fixed,precision=3]{\tick}\possiblytrimmedtick% <- missing } added
    \pgfmathparse{\possiblytrimmedtick == \tick ? int(1):int(0)}%
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\relax$\tick$\else\fi%
  },
  typeset ticklabels with strut% <- added
]
\addplot+ { x^3 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]